# Finding period in this sin graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(http://media.collegeboard.com/digitalServices/image/clep/pcal.q1.2.png)

I cannot find any common points in which I can take the distance in this graph. How would you find the period then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it traverses one and a half periods by $2\pi$, so its period will be $\frac{4\pi}{3}$.

Comment: Now it seems very obvious to me! Thanks!